# Get current user id without access_token for poll app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, userid

Can I get the user_id without him acepting my app?

I need to build a poll app that should not require auth do vote. If I can store the user_id I can make sure all votes are unique...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very limited what you can get when the user didn't install your app. Because getting the uid is the same as getting all public data for the user (you can query all public data with that uid and any access_token of some other user). So, unfortunately, you have to ask for an app install when you want to use Facebook to track if the user has already voted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get that information without the user sharing it with your app by way of accepting/authorizing your app.

If you could get the user ID without the user authorizing your app, then it would violate the Platform policies https://developers.facebook.com/policy/.

Answer (score -1):

Just call the following api to get user id in response.

```
 FB.api('/me', 'post', function(response)
{
console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Is this a canvas app or page tab app ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The question clearly states "should not require auth". And this means: No user access token.

Comment: I was looking how to get current user id with token, and only this answer helped me, even if it not proper one to this question.